# Need Webkit and C++ example code for reading and displaying HTML from file

Tags: c++, html, webkit

I'm looking for some C++/webkit example code or some grate tutorials. Here is what i need in the example:
  1. Read Html file from disk, and render the htmlvascript and display content
  2. I need so its independent from any other web browsers on pc, using only webkit.

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Qt because it would be dead simple with it?

Basically something like this:

```
QWebView view;
view.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
view.showMaximized();
```

Comment: Yes, just use file:// protocol or if you want to load from inside Qt resource file protocol qrc:// will do it.